# given an ordered sequence of integers write an algorithm to construct a binarySearchTree with ideal Topology?

Tags: java, recursion, return, binary-search-tree

Ok this looks better, but gives a null pointer exception ?

public static BST idealTop(Comparable [] C){

```
        BST X = new BST();

        helperIdeal(C, X.root,(C.length/2));

        return X;
    }

    public static void helperIdeal(Comparable [] C, node R,int mid){


            if(mid<0||mid>C.length-1){
                R.left = null;
                            R.right = null;


        }

            else{
             R.data = C[mid];
             helperIdeal(C,R.left,mid/2);
             helperIdeal(C,R.right,(mid*2)-1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: the code is changed now, I'm stumped at the terminating condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to consider this a homework question...

The trick to the best algorithm here is that the list is sorted and a BST when read along the bottom is always sorted too.

Think about your data structure and how you can reference each node in the tree. If you do it well, you should get a linear algorithm.

Comment: why do I keep getting this "I think it's a homework question" ?

Comment: what do you mean by a linear algorithm ?

Comment: @M.K ... because "given an ordered sequence of integers write an algorithm to construct a binarySearchTree with ideal Topology" sounds exactly like homework would be phrased.

Comment: A linear algorithm is a solution to a problem with O(N) time. In laymans terms that means that the time it takes to compute the solution is linearly proportional (Y=MX+C) to how many elements there are. Here X is N multiplied by time for each N (number of tree items) and C is just overhead to your algorithm and not considered proportional to N at all. That is probably as simply (and maybe not 100% accurate) as I can put it.

IMO Big-O notation is not to be used to calculate exact computing time but rather give you an idea the side affects to computing time of each component of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Binary search tree with ideal topology means, balanced search tree. so u get logn.

In order to do that, you need to start from the beginning, and possible keep multiple pointers in your array, and move your pointers in two halves of your array until you put all you elements to tree and tree is balanced.

easy.

Comment: you can do both iteratively and recursively. iteratively would be easier.